# How to compare a returned string from a method with another string in the main method?

Tags: java

The idea is that the while loop should loop through the code if the result is "wrong password",
until the correct password is entered and breaks the loop when it matches the login method return value.

```
while (true){
   System.out.println("\nLogin: ");
   System.out.println("\nEnter a username: ");
   String loginUsername = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter a password: ");
   String loginPassword = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println(login(loginUsername,loginPassword));
   if (login(loginUsername,loginPassword).equalsIgnoreCase("Successfully logged in!")) {
       break;
   }
}
```

this code is the return statements from the login method

```
if (check == true){
        return ("\nSuccessfully logged in!");
    } else {
        return ("\nWrong username/password");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You are currently comparing a string that starts with a newline to one that doesn't, so that might be your issue? If not, then please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: When the console outputs "Successfully logged in!" the loop doesn't break and that should be because the if-condition isn't met, so that leads me to think that I don't get the right value from login(loginUsername,loginPassword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But `"Successfully logged in!"` is not the same string as `"\nSuccessfully logged in!"`.

More importantly... Why use strings for this at all?  If you want to know whether something is true or false, there's a perfectly good data type to convey that information.  Return that type instead:

```
return check;
```

Rename the method to something more meaningful than `login`, and use its result in a semantically clear condition:

```
if (isLoginSuccessful(loginUsername,loginPassword)) {
    break;
}
```

This puts the semantics of what you're doing *in the code itself*, rather than in magic strings that you need to copy/paste everywhere and manually keep track of.  Which, already in this one tiny example, you've lost track of by making the strings different.  (With the added benefit that using booleans for conditional logic *probably* performs a little better than string comparison.)